# Filter data from df using date picker - tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi I am trying to filter the data based on date range from below df and create output as df1 using tkinter - python

**df:**

| ID | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 361 | 10/15/2023 | 21 |
| 865 | 8/8/2023 | 565 |
| 66 | 1/22/2023 | 263 |
| 54 | 5/6/2023 | 350 |
| 989 | 10/30/2023 | 253 |
| 843 | 6/26/2023 | 62 |
| 957 | 10/17/2023 | 476 |

Output should be result from df by filtering data between any range (for ex: below df1 filtered after selecting date between 01/01/2023 to 05/31/2023 (mm/dd/yyyy)
**df1_1**:

| ID | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 66 | 1/22/2023 | 263 |
| 54 | 5/6/2023 | 350 |

The code i have written is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkcalendar
from datetime import timedelta

root = Tk()

def date_range(start,stop):
    global dates # If you want to use this outside of functions
     
    dates = []
    diff = (stop-start).days
    for i in range(diff+1):
        day = start + timedelta(days=i)
        dates.append(day)
    if dates:
        print(dates) # Print it, or even make it global to access it outside this
    else:
        print('Make sure the end date is later than start date')

date1 = tkcalendar.DateEntry(root)
date1.pack(padx=10,pady=10)

date2 = tkcalendar.DateEntry(root)
date2.pack(padx=10,pady=10)

Button(root,text='Find range',command=lambda: date_range(date1.get_date(),date2.get_date())).pack() 

root.mainloop()
```

How do i include my required functionality (creating df1 from df in above code)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: just for some clarity, is the df you are referring to a pandas dataframe ?

Comment: thanks karan, yes i have a df dataframe in my environment

Comment: Try `df1 = df[df["Date"].between(start, stop)]`.